# auto remove the unused imports for angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am already using [`TypeScrit Hero 3.0.0`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbbit.typescript-hero) and as it promotes:

> Sort and organize your imports (sort and **remove unused**)

But it seems, it just won't **remove unused** in my VSCode.

#### F.Y.I

```
$ code -v
1.30.2
61122f88f0bf01e2ac16bdb9e1bc4571755f5bd8
x64
```

Have any idea to handle this weird thing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using VS Code's built-in `Organize imports` command? It sorts and removed unused imports for JS+TS

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it. Thank you!